# How to know the ES index from the ES query?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, sense, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-indices

I have the Elastic search query(got it from the XHR call - using ARC), but need to know to which index, the query is being hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any item, in "hits"/"hits" "_index" is what you need.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awaUa.png)

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you